# how to use await in string function

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use await in string function. I need to append some strings to simple string which i have been trying to with no avail. SImilar scenario is given below,

```
String url =  appendUrl();

appendUrl(){
  String a = 'www.google.com';
  String b = await getDeviceId();  // it gets device id from other packages
  String c = a + '/?abc=' + b;
  return c;    // expected result => www.google.com/?abc=somedeviceid
}
```

Since string is to be returned I cant add async to appendUrl and thus await cant be use to get device id. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: can't you get the value b first, then only call `appendUrl()` ?

Comment: If `appendUrl` depends on an asynchronous function, then `appendUrl` is necessarily asynchronous as well and must return a `Future` too.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using then() instead of async/await

```
appendUrl() {
  String a = 'www.google.com';
  getDeviceId().then((value) {
    setState(() {
      url = a + '/?abc=' + value;
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: i believe that if url is used in the UI, setState is required to reflect the change onto UI

Comment: @DungNgo thank you for the comment but i am still getting an error. It says Class 'String' has no instance method 'then'.

Comment: Using `.then()` is no different than using `await`.